# Hide Element with Bootstrap Yet Maintain Unique ID

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, dom, visibility

I have a simple need--I want to responsively render a div that I later need to manipulate using JavaScript. Consider this code:

```
<div id="test" class="visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block>Large Viewport</div>
<div id="test" class="visible-xs-block">Small Viewport</div>
```

**Please Note: The example text in the div above is not my actual case. My actual case includes a JQuery UI control within each div, something like this:**

```
<div id="test" class="visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block>[[JQUERY CONTROL]]</div>
<div id="test" class="visible-xs-block">[[JQUERY CONTROL]]</div>
```

**I use JQuery to set properties on the JQUERY control and those properties must be slightly different when the viewport is "xs" versus when it's "sm", "md", or "lg".**

This works well: When I show the browser at 1024x768, I see "Large Viewport"; when I reduce he browser to 640x960, I see "Small Viewport". The problem is that both tags always appear on the rendered DOM and both have an ID attribute value of "test". I use that unique ID in Javascript to find the Div tag--and now my JavaScript sees two of them.

How can I address this problem--either by having a unique ID for each DIV or by somehow getting the "hidden" DIV not to render at all? Ideally, I'd like a solution that uses only Bootstrap features (which I'm relatively new to) and not a solution that requires JavaScript or JQuery.

If I must use JS/JQuery, then what is the best way to determine if the tag was rendered by Bootstrap? I really don't want to use media queries or try to determine the viewport size on my own as ultimately I want Bootstrap to have the "decision-making authority" as to whether the div gets rendered or not--I would only want to know what Bootstrap decided and then interact with the visible div as needed.

Thank you.

Comment: The best solution really depends on why you need the ID there in the first place: what are you doing in Javascript with the `div` once you fetch it by its ID? Possible solutions, dependant on the answer to that question, include: `<div id="test"><span class="visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block">Large Viewport</span><span class="visible-xs-block">Small Viewport</span></div>`, or using a class instead of an ID, or a number of other options.

Comment: I was trying to provide a very simple example--showing the ID--so as to keep focus on the ID part of the question. I have clarified this in my edited question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification.

The simplest solution may be to just use `class` instead of `ID`, or give them distinct IDs, and simply apply your Javascript to both even though one of them is invisible.

If this is not possible, due to something your jQuery UI controller is doing that shouldn't be done to the hidden `div`, then consider giving them both the same class (e.g. `mytestclass`) and selecting the visible one using:

```
$('.mytestclass:visible')
```

as your selector. This will only select the one which [currently has a width or height](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) in your layout, which the one hidden by Bootstrap will not (due to the `display: none;` Bootstrap gives it).

But don't forget that if the viewport width later changes (browser resize, mobile rotate, whatever) you may need to listen for this event and reapply your code to the newly visible `div`.

Does this sound like something that would work for your scenario?

Comment: Shai, thank you so much--I think you nailed it! I will experiment tonight or tomorrow and will round-trip back here with my findings.

Comment: Shai, I like your idea but ran into a problem: I am testing what's visible in a JQuery resize event handler:

    $(window).resize(function () {
                ...
            });

It seems that this handler sometimes fires before Bootstrap has completed updating the DOM so I sometimes get 'undefined' return from my $('.mytestclass:visible') selector. How can I wire-up my resize test to fire only once Bootstrap has done what it needs to do with the DOM?

Comment: I posed a new question related to this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590676/bootstrap-resize-finished-event-or-callback